# Is "remained considered guilty" grammatical?

Tags: participles, predicative-complements, adjectival-phrases

I'm currently reading Huddleston and Pullum (2002). In section 1.3 (p. 79), they note that the following sentence is ungrammatical:

(1) The boss seemed considered guilty of bias.

I agree that this is ungrammatical. But they also say that "remain" works the same way as "seem." So I would conclude that the following sentence should also be ungrammatical:

(2) Until he was proven innocent, the man remained considered guilty.

But (2) doesn't sound ungrammatical to me. It's awkward but it doesn't sound incorrect.  If you replace "guilty" with an NP like "a guilty felon," it still doesn't sound wrong to me.

I can find (admittedly rare) uses of "remained considered" like this online (see [PubMed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26334031/), [Boston.com](https://www.boston.com/news/crime/2020/05/27/peter-manfredonia-case-timeline/?amp=1)).

So, is my intuition broken, or is this usage indeed valid?

Comment: Awkward, but not ungrammatical.

Comment: An _as_ before _guilty_ would go a long way towards marking the forest of predicates _remained considered guilty_, which is as @Robusto says.

Comment: There comes a point where 'awkward' and 'ungrammatical' touch. Both are usage-driven.

Comment: Don't forget, _participium_ was one of the Original Eight Parts of Speech (_partes orationis_ in Latin). This was before they discovered the adjective, which was missing from Roman lists. We tend to treat participles as verb forms, but the Romans considered them unique; of course Latin had a whole lot more participles than English does and used them more often.

Comment: Can you Post a specific link to Huddleston and Pullum (2002)  section 1.3 (p. 79)? I for one found those details TL/DR… which is the first time I've Posted that failiong.

Comment: 'The boss seemed considered guilty of bias' will never work by itself, even if it might be grammatical.

Whatever Huddleston and Pullum say, what you need might be 'The boss seemed guilty of bias' or 'The boss was/had been considered guilty of bias'

Answer (score 1):

"The man seemed guilty."

"the man was considered guilty."

The meanings of the two sentences above are rather similar.   It is at best a redundancy.

But using it twice changes the meaning in the same way a double negative becomes a positive.

He seemed considered guilty.   He wasn't *actually* considered guilty,  he just seemed as if he was considered guilty.

The phrase "he remained considered guilty" does not have the same problems.